# Why batch files resolve && and || at the same time unless the first action has an &?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch

I'm running a command with an action for success and another for failure in a batch file. The thing is, unless the first action has a `&` it wont work. For example this wont work as it will execute both commands no matter what:

```
7z a "FILE.7z" "INPUT" ( && sounder "Success.wav" ) || ( sounder "Error.wav" & echo. & pause & exit )
```

Even tried doing this instead:

```
( 7z a "FILE.7z" "INPUT" && sounder "Success.wav" ) || ( sounder "Error.wav" & echo. & pause & exit )
```

But this does works:

```
7z a "FILE.7z" "INPUT" ( && sounder "Success.wav" & echo. ) || ( sounder "Error.wav" & echo. & pause & exit )
```

Why is that?

I'm using Windows 10 and cmd.

Comment: Please specify your OPERATING SYSTEM & the shell you are using (bash, command prompt, powershell, etc.). If Windows (likely based on your 'batch' word) this may help:
https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: I added the info, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[This site](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) shows this example:
`commandA && commandB || commandC`

> If commandA succeeds run commandB, if commandA fails run commandC
> ( Note that if commandB fails, that will also trigger running commandC )

Based on that I BELIEVE this could work?

`7z a "FILE.7z" "INPUT" && sounder "Success.wav" || sounder "Error.wav"`

As for the WHY batch scripting is VERY finicky when you are concatenating multiple commands on a single line. You could CHECK if a command produces an error (anything besides 0 generally) then do this or that:

```
7z a "FILE.7z"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (sounder "Error.wav") ELSE (sounder "Error.wav")
```

More reading:

- https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html
- https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-error.html
- https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html
- https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html
- https://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchstart.php

Comment: Yes, I ruled out sounder returning other than 0 because I can hear the "success.wav" file and I used `echo %errorlevel%`. I also have another script that does some additional stuff besides playing the "success.wav" file and those actions are executed so sounder is returning 0. `7z a OUT.7z IN && ( sounder "success.wav" && rmdir IN ) || ( sounder "error.wav" )` with that command the directory is removed and for that to happen sounder had to return 0.

Comment: Parentheses are used to split commands over multiple lines so you are using them a bit oddly which is where I think your trouble is coming in. Maybe middle/bottom of this page will answer your question: https://www.robvanderwoude.com/comments.php